# Why does my string remove multiple characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've noticed a very curious phenomenon here. I've instantiated a global variable (`usrPIN`), and I'm comparing it to a local variable (`c`). When I input a value (in this case, four zeros), the value is chopped off, creating a string that is one character long. Why?

```
usrPIN
...
def login():
    global usrPIN
    ...
    c = str(input("Enter PIN"))
    print usrPIN
    print str(c)
    if usrPIN == c:
        mainMenu()
    else:
        print "Incorrect PIN"
        login()
```

[image]

What on earth is going on?

Comment: Use `raw_input(...)` rather than `str(input(...))` - `str(eval(raw_input('0000')))` is effectively `str(int('0000'))`, which is `'0'`. Also, while you're here: don't use globals.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You were correct. Additionally, whilst I've read about globals being somewhat dangerous, I have multiple functions that I'm passing these variables to. Using globals is the most logical solution I've found so far - I've only been learning Python for two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.x `input()` does automatic evaluation. What this means is when I do:

```
input(0.2757)
```

Python evaluates that to be a float. Similarly, in your case `0000` is evaluated as an integer and since four zeros is the same as one zero, it chops those away. In Python 2.x it's generally always recommended to use `raw_input()` for safety.

Note: `raw_input()` in Python 2.x always returns a string.

Comment: This was the one - OOI, why does this occur even if I specify `str()`? Is it because the implicit conversion happens *before* the specification?

Comment: @Wolfish Internally `input()` looks kind of like `eval(raw_input())` so when you say `str(input())` you're actually saying `str(eval(raw_input()))` so the evaluation has already occurred before you ask for a string conversion.